# Unsubscribing from follow up comments

Tags: comment-form, subscriptions

In the [comment form](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/#comment-submission-form), I can have a checkbox that allows me to tell EE to notify me of follow up comments

```
{exp:comment:form channel="news" preview="channel/preview"}
    ...
    <textarea name="comment" cols="70" rows="10">{comment}</textarea>
    ...
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="notify_me" value="yes" {notify_me} /> Notify me of follow-up comments?</label><br />
    ...
{/exp:comment:form}
```

I want the users to be able to toggle this feature since some of them want this feature disabled.

So I tried a solution. I unchecked the checkbox and submit with a blank comment textarea field.

However, when doing that I am shown an EE error that tells me that the comment field should not be blank.

My question is, how do I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the **Comment Notification Links Tag**
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/#comment-notification-links-tag

The `{exp:comment:notification_links}` tag can be [used] to allow members to subscribe to an entry without commenting via a simple link. This tag may only be used on a single entry page.
(edit: or provide parameters for entry_id or url_title to help the tag find the entry)

```
{exp:comment:notification_links entry_id="x"}
        {if subscribed}
                <h5><a href="{unsubscribe_link}">Unsubscribe to comment notification for this entry.</a></h5>
        {if:else}
                <h5><a href="{subscribe_link}">Subscribe to comment notification for this entry.</a></h5>
        {/if}
{/exp:comment:notification_links}
```

**edit:** if you want authors to be able to unsubscribe, make sure that
"notification of authors" in channel settings for a channel is set to OFF.
Authors then need to subscribe themselves (or with a custom extension)
via: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/6393/155

Comment: OK, I tried doing this solution but nothing was outputted by the tag.

Comment: you can set parameters to help the tag. entry_id="{segment_x} or url_title="{segment_x}". Also, the visitor has to be logged in!

Comment: Ok, I got it to work by adding the entry_id parameter